# Properly formatting an AWS CLI command for ACM to use S3 storage links

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-acm

Using AWS CLI for ACM's 'import-certificate' to re-import a renewed cert, chain and private key for a LetsEncrypt certificate that gets dropped off in an S3 bucket. It seems the usual file parameter syntax notation.
I am using [aws-cli/1.18.69 Python/3.8.10 Linux/5.14.0-1056-oem botocore/1.16.19]

Here is what is not working:

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate fileb://s3://foo-bucket-001/bar.com/cert.pem --certificate-chain fileb://s3://foo-bucket-001/bar.com/chain.pem --private-key fileb://s3://foo-bucket-001/bar.com/privkey.pem --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:000000000000:certificate/d3bbe6f3-c479-4bbe-ad16-cc97745501a5
```

Error Message:
`Error parsing parameter '--certificate': Unable to load paramfile fileb://s3://foo-bucket-001/townsquareignite.com/cert.pem: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://foo-bucket-001/townsquareignite.com/cert.pem'` 
I've tried **s3://**, **file://**, and **fileb://**,using the ARN for the S3 objects.
Having no joy.

Using **fileb://path/to-local/cert.pem** does work, so obviously it's just the command binary file syntax to the files in S3 bucket arenot correct. But I cannot find any documentation now previous answer.

Any AWS CLI ACM via S3 guidance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you cannot use this cli command with s3. If you type `aws acm import-certificate help` there is nothing about s3 at all. A private certificate usually is very sensitive information and I think AWS doesn't encourage uploading it to s3. Or maybe it was an original idea when they developed this CLI sub-command.

Unfortunately, you'll have to import it once from your local machine and then refer to its ARN in your automation/infrastructure code.

Comment: Also looking on boto3 docs https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/acm.html#ACM.Client.import_certificate it doesn't look like they support s3 urls

Comment: Thank you, @morkot
I saw this in the documentation 
_If you are making an HTTP or HTTPS Query request, include these arguments as BLOBs._
and thought it was perhaps either an omission or contained in a seemingly unrelated section of AWS CLI documentation.

To clarify, I am using this to automate the process of importing third party certs to ACM for use as Alternate Domain Name for CloudFront distro's as part of CloudFormation stacks. I will simply adjust the script(s) to pull the file "local" before the import-certificate sub-command.

Comment: I asked AWS Support if it is possible to add this to the API sub-commands. Many thanks for your help and clarity.